# How to drag RenderTransform with mouse in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to make a viewer which will move and zoom children with mouse.
So, I create the class `TransformViewer : UserControl` and override an event methods.
But I have a problem with OnMouseMove. When I translate RenderTransform, OnMouseMove is called continuously, even if I don't move mouse. And RenderTransform shakes.

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
        Point mouse = e.GetPosition( this );
        Vector delta = Point.Subtract( mouse, oldMouse );
        oldMouse = mouse;

        if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown( Key.LeftShift ) &&
            (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed || e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)) {
            Matrix matrix = transform.Matrix;
            matrix.Translate( delta.X, delta.Y );
            transform.Matrix = matrix;

            e.Handled = true;
            RenderTransform = transform;
        }

    }
```

Why so?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to get the mouse position from the element when you set its RenderTransform at the same time. Changing the RenderTransform will have an effect of the coordinates reported by e.GetPosition.

Comment: And what should I do?

Comment: Get the mouse position from the parent element, e.g. a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Better to change RenderTransform of a child.

```
public class TransformViewer : UserControl {

    private readonly MatrixTransform transform = new MatrixTransform();
    private Point pressedMouse;


    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        pressedMouse = transform.Inverse.Transform( e.GetPosition( this ) );
    }


    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
        if(e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {
            Point mouse = transform.Inverse.Transform( e.GetPosition( this ) );
            Vector delta = Point.Subtract( mouse, pressedMouse ); // delta from old mouse to current mouse
            var translate = new TranslateTransform( delta.X, delta.Y );
            transform.Matrix = translate.Value * transform.Matrix;

            ((UIElement) Content).RenderTransform = transform;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }


    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
            float scale = 1.1f;
            if(e.Delta < 0) scale = 1f / scale;
            Point mouse = e.GetPosition( this );

            Matrix matrix = transform.Matrix;
            matrix.ScaleAt( scale, scale, mouse.X, mouse.Y );
            transform.Matrix = matrix;

            ((UIElement) Content).RenderTransform = transform;
            e.Handled = true;
    }

}
```